# Powershell dropdown select item, loads a specific text file into text box on form

Tags: powershell, dropdown

In Powershell I want to have a dropdown list with following items:

Textfile1
Textfile2
Textfile3

When one if the list items is selected it reads file contents into textbox on form.

For example:

dropdown "Textfile1" is selected, that loads c:\Textfile1.txt into textbox on form.

already tried a function with `if/elseif` but having difficulty tying it together, unfortunately still learning Powershell.

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend create a form with a dropdown list and return the choice from that, as Powershell is pretty much not built for that stuff.

Of course,I dont think it is impossible, but i'd use in this case the **Out-GridView** function to do work that is similar to your needs.

```
$files_location = "C:\yourlocation\*"


$options = Get-ChildItem $files_location


$user_choice = $options | Out-GridView -Title 'Select the File you want to show'  -PassThru

Switch ($user_choice)  {

    #Condition to check:

    { $user_choice.Name -eq 'textfile1.txt' }


    #Do something:
    {
        Write-Host "Im going to open $($user_choice.Name)"
        #Open the file:
        start "$user_choice"
    }

    #Continue your switch/case conditions here...

}
```

I'm using the output object from the **Get-ChildItem** function and outputting a gridview from that.

You can change the Switch case to **if statement** if you more comfortable with this function:

```
$files_location = "C:\yourlocation\*"


$options = Get-ChildItem $files_location


$user_choice = $options | Out-GridView -Title 'Select the File you want to show'  -PassThru

if ($user_choice.Name -eq 'a.txt')
{
    start $user_choice
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works great! 
How to make this portion dynamic too? 
if ($user_choice.Name -eq 'a.txt') .  

I don't want to hard code "a.txt" file name and -eq then use verify it matches to do something

basically any file will be selected and then displayed
 but there won't be different conditions for each file 
(Although I appreciate the example as it will be useful later)

Comment: figured it out

{ $user_choice.Name -eq 'a.txt' }

should be { $user_choice.Name -eq "$(user_choice.Name)" }